# How can i hide counter days when it gets zero?

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I have a counter that shows 0 and i want to hide it when it's getting 0.
So if the counter shows (0 days 6 hours 25 minutes) i want it to be (6 hours 25 minutes), just hide it on 0...
this is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("April 12, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary operator to chceck if days == 0

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ((days) ? days + "d " : '') + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("April 12, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ((days) ? days + "d " : '') + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check when `days === 0` and fill it empty

```
days = days === 0 ? '' : days + "d "

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
```

The same with hours and minutes

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it for all your outputs and show something like `1d 0h 52m 0s` not as `1d 52m`  then the logic should be something like:

```
// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
                         ((!days) ? '' : days + "d ") + 
                         ((!days && !hours) ? '' : hours + "h ") +
                         ((!days && !hours && !minutes) ? '' : minutes + "m ") + 
                         ((!days && !hours && !minutes && !seconds) ? '' : seconds + "s ";
```

this way times like `0d 0h 52m 0s` are presented like `52m 0s`

Answer (score 1):

You can set a condition when you change the time in through `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` as,

```
(days === 0 ? '' : days + "d ") +
(hours === 0 ? '' : hours + "h ")+
(minutes === 0 ? '' : minutes + "m ")+ 
 seconds + "s ";
```

This will check for the zero value for `days`, `hours` and `minutes` and assign `null` in the HTML,

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("April 12, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    (days === 0 ? '' : days + "d ") +
    (hours === 0 ? '' : hours + "h ")+
    (minutes === 0 ? '' : minutes + "m ")+ 
     seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```